# Asymptotic solution--partial sum of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, asymptotics

Let $a_{rj}=\ln r+(j-1)\ln\ln r-\ln(j-1)!$ for $j=1,2,\dots$, and $a_{r0}=\ln r$. Set $v_j=a_{rj}+u$ for $j=0,1,\dots$. I read the following in a paper, but I don't know how to figure it out.

For any $m=1,2,\dots$,
$$
r\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}\frac{v_j^{j}e^{-v_j}}{j!}=e^{-u}+o(1)\;\;\mbox{as}\;\;r\to\infty.
$$

I have made an attempt:

Note that
\begin{align*}
r\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}\frac{v_j^{j}e^{-v_j}}{j!}&=r\left(e^{-v_0}+v_{1}e^{-v_1}+\sum_{j=2}^{m-1}\frac{v_j^{j}e^{-v_j}}{j!}\right)\\
&=r\left(\frac{e^{-u}}{r}+e^{-u}\sum_{j=2}^{m-1}\frac{(a_{rj}+u)^{j}}{j!}\cdot\frac{(j-1)!}{r(\ln r)^{j-1}}\right)\\
&=e^{-u}+e^{-u}\sum_{j=2}^{m-1}\frac{a_{rj}+u}{j}\cdot\left(\frac{a_{rj}+u}{\ln r}\right)^{j-1},
\end{align*}
where the second equality follows from the fact that $v_1=\infty$ and the definition of $a_{rj}$. However, the last term on the right hand side of the last equality does not tend to zero as $r\to\infty$.

Could any one give me a help or a hint? Any reference would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: Is it $a_{0j}=\ln r$ or $a_{r0}$? What is the domain of $r$?

Comment: Thanks for the correction. And, r is an integer.

Comment: Is $a_{r0} = \infty$ since $(0-1)! = \infty$?

Comment: Actually, $a_{r0}$ is not defined clearly, and I thought it should be $r$. However, I still don't know how to prove the asymptotic result even if $a_{r0}=\infty$.

Comment: Could you give a reference for which paper this was found in?

Comment: "On Birthday, Collectors', Occupancy and Other Classical Urn Problems" by Lars Holst (1986). It is found in the proof of Lemma 4.3 on page 19.

Comment: Thanks, I got the paper and took a look at the relevant portion. I think I see what's going on. I'll try to return within the next couple of days to give you an answer here.

Comment: Thank you very much! No hurry. Take your time.